# system check error when try to run server in django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-templates, django-urls

i am newbie in django framework 
trying to build template for upload image in filesystem and show this image on page. 
first i get error first i get error in File

```
"/home/tac/Desktop/myproject/myapp/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
url(r'^$', 'list', name='list'),
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/**init**.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

somehow I solve this error but after that i face another error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv4rW.png)

myapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = ('myapp.views',
    url(r'^$', list, name='list'),
    url(r'^list/$', list, name='list'),
)
```

myproject/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
        (r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
        (r'^$', 'myapp.views.index'),
        (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**ERROR**
nhandled exception in thread started by 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 420, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern ('^$', 'myapp.views.index') is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.
    HINT: Try using url() instead of a tuple.
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern ('^admin/', ([, , , , , , \d+)/(?P.+)/$>,  (None:None) ^auth/user/>,  (None:None) ^auth/group/>, auth)/$>], 'admin', 'admin')) is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.
    HINT: Try using url() instead of a tuple.
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern ('^myapp/', (, None, None)) is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.
    HINT: Try using url() instead of a tuple.

System check identified 3 issues (0 silenced).

Comment: copy your urls.py file here

Comment: added the both urls.py @SnakeFcz

Comment: i found the error in the urls.py and i have answerd belwo find it, you need to append the static url in the urlpatterns list

Comment: thanks for the reply but i still get same error this one:  django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues @SnakeFcz

Comment: explain more about your need ,

Comment: i update error in my question. @SnakeFcz  and  i am  trying to build template for upload image in filesystem and show this image on page

Comment: you got it,...i have update the answer , the error is url() is not there, please check the anwer

Comment: thanks for taking your time for helping me but again another error raise please look into this ERROR                                                                  File "/home/tac/Desktop/myproject/myproject/urls.py", line 11, in <module>
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.index'),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include(). @SnakeFcz

Comment: try `from myapp import views` and use as  `url(r'^$', views.index)`

Comment: feels you miss a trailing comma `,` at end of every url

Comment: after doing what itzmeontv said, error changed to this :                                                                  django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern 'myapp.views' is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.
 HINT: Try removing the string 'myapp.views'. The list of urlpatterns should not have a prefix string as the first element.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
@SnakeFcz

Comment: please follow the django documentation properly if you are beginner in the django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myproject/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)





myapp/urls.py 

from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    # url(r'^$', views.list, name='list'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^list/$', views.list, name='list'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
        url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.index'),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: can you tell in which urls.py are you talking about  myapp/urls.py or myproject/urls.py @SnakeFcz